# Notice Undefined index: ORDER BY in phpmyadmin stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I've written an procedure which looks like the below code:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE get_news(IN lat DECIMAL(10,8), IN lon DECIMAL(11,8), IN miles FLOAT)
BEGIN
    SELECT `latitude`,`longitude`,COUNT(*) count, (
        3959 *
        acos(
            cos(radians(38.9071923)) *
            cos(radians(`latitude`)) *
            cos(radians(`longitude`) - radians(77.0368707)) +
            sin(radians(38.9071923)) *
            sin(radians(`latitude`))
        )
    ) `distance`
    FROM `news`
    GROUP BY `latitude`,`longitude`
    HAVING `distance` < miles;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

and when I call this procedure from phpmyadmin, I get the following error:

```
Notice in ./libraries/sql-parser/src/Utils/Query.php#570
 Undefined index: ORDER BY

Backtrace

./libraries/sql-parser/src/Utils/Query.php#666: SqlParser\Utils\Query::getClause(
object,
object,
string 'ORDER BY',
integer -1,
boolean false,
)
./libraries/DisplayResults.php#1385: SqlParser\Utils\Query::replaceClause(
object,
object,
string 'ORDER BY',
string '',
)
./libraries/DisplayResults.php#4368: PMA\libraries\DisplayResults->_getUnsortedSqlAndSortByKeyDropDown(
array,
string '',
)
./libraries/sql.lib.php#1643: PMA\libraries\DisplayResults->getTable(
object,
array,
array,
boolean false,
)
./libraries/sql.lib.php#1965: PMA_getHtmlForSqlQueryResultsTable(
object,
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
array,
boolean false,
integer 80,
integer 80,
NULL,
object,
array,
)
./libraries/sql.lib.php#2184: PMA_getQueryResponseForResultsReturned(
object,
array,
string 'news-api',
string '',
NULL,
NULL,
object,
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
integer 80,
integer 80,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'CALL get_news_count(38.9071923,-77.0368707,100)',
NULL,
)
./import.php#800: PMA_executeQueryAndGetQueryResponse(
array,
boolean false,
string 'news-api',
string '',
NULL,
string 'CALL get_news_count(38.9071923,-77.0368707,100)',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'db_structure.php',
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'CALL get_news_count(38.9071923,-77.0368707,100)',
NULL,
NULL,
)
```

When I run the query directly, It works with no error, but when I call the procedure, I get the above errors in phpmyadmin. If anybody has faced this problem, please help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue. It might be a phpmyadmin issue. Please let me know if you figured out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You have used `HAVING` without an Aggregate Function. You could have used `HAVING COUNT(xyz) = 5` if you really want to use `HAVING` clause here. Otherwise, just use `WHERE` clause.

**Having** is a **Where** clause for Aggregate functions. Whenever you want to use a condition with aggregate functions like AVG, SUM, COUNT, etc, you need to use **Having**. If you just want to check a condition, then use **Where** clause instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT `latitude`,`longitude`,COUNT(*) count, (
            3959 *
            acos(
                cos(radians(38.9071923)) *
                cos(radians(`latitude`)) *
                cos(radians(`longitude`) - radians(77.0368707)) +
                sin(radians(38.9071923)) *
                sin(radians(`latitude`))
            )
        ) `distance`
        FROM `news`
    WHERE`distance` < miles
        GROUP BY `latitude`,`longitude`;
```

Comment: Please explain why this answer works.